# Fourier transform for Helmholtz equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

> The Helmholtz equation takes the form,
>   $$u_{xx} + u_{yy} + k^
> 2u = f(x, y),$$
>   for $−∞ < x < ∞$, $−∞ < y < ∞$.
>
> i) Assuming that the functions $u(x, y)$ and $f(x, y)$ have Fourier transforms
>   show that the solution to this equation can formally be written:
>
> $$u(x, y) = −
> \frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
> e^{−i(λ(x−ζ)+µ(y−η))} \frac{f(ζ, η)}{λ^2 + µ^2 − k^2}dλ  dµ d ζ dη$$
>
> ii) Is this result consistent with the special case where $f(x, y) = 0$?

I tried taking fourier transform with respect to $x$. ($ F(f^{''}(x)) = -s^2F(f))$ and obtained the inhomogenous equation. 
$\frac{\partial^2F(u)}{\partial y^2} + (k^2 - s^2) F(u)=F(f)$ . Not quite sure if taking right direction or how to solve this equation correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Take the Fourier transform with respect to $x$ and $y$. This gives you an algebraic equation for $\hat{u}$. Solve for $\hat{u}$ and take the inverse transform(s) to get the desired solution,

Comment: Can you start it off? I'm confused how you take with respect to x and y. I'm still new to fourier transforms. Thanks. @Winther

Comment: Take first wrt $x$ and the wrt $y$ so that $\hat{f}(k_x,k_y) = \int e^{i k_x x} e^{i k_y y}f(x,y){\rm d}x{\rm d}y$. With this $u_{xx}(x,y)\to -k_x^2 \hat{u}(k_x,k_y)$ and $u_{yy}(x,y)\to -k_y^2 \hat{u}(k_x,k_y)$. The inverse transform is simply $u(x,y) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int e^{-ik_x x}e^{-ik_y y} \hat{u}(k_x,k_y){\rm d}k_x{\rm d}k_y$

Comment: Just wondering for the f(x,y) in the pde. Does taking fourier transform respect to x and y give f(x,y). $  (k^2 - s^2 - t^2) F(s,t)=F^x(F^y(f)))$ where $F^x$ is taking the fourier transform wrt x. So my question is if $F^x(F^y(f))) = f$, since the final answer in part i has $f(ζ, η)$ instead of $F^x(F^y(f(ζ, η)))$ @Winther

Comment: Taking the FT of the equation simply means to multiply by $e^{ik_x x}e^{ik_y x}$ and integrate over $x$ and $y$ (btw what I call $k_x,k_y$ you call $\zeta,\eta$). Thus taking the FT of the equation the right hand side becomes $\int f(x,y)e^{ik_x x}e^{ik_y y}{\rm d}x{\rm d}y$ (which is starting to look like what you are to show...). It's not true that $F^x(F^y(f)) = f$.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but i just realised your definition of the fourier transform is different to wiki. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform. Shouldn't it be $\int \int e^{-ik_x x }e^{-ik_y y }f(x,y)dxdy?$. I mean why does yours work too, as your definition of the fourier transform leads to the answer required. Thanks. @Winther

Comment: There are many different conventions. All are ok as long as you use a consistent choice for both the FT and the inverse FT (+ vs - and where to place the $2\pi$'s). You should use the one you know and are comfortable with. Both choices will work to give the answer, but to compare to the answer in the book you might need to make a few simple substitutions in the end depending on what convention you choose.

Comment: Cool. Also I have an extra question about ii) Is this result consistent with the special case where f(x,y)=0? For the case where f(x,y), can we say its consistent as f(x,y) = 0 means u(x,y) = 0. Am I interpreting this question correctly? @Winther

Comment: Yes I think so. Also note that the solution here is only *one* solution. You would get a more general solution if you add a solution of the homogenous problem $u_{xx}+u_{yy}+k^2u = 0$ (e.g. $u = A\sin(kx)$ is a solution). However this doesn't have a FT in the traditional sense (e.g. $\sin(kx)$ has a FT that is a distribution) so it's not included by that assumption. Maybe I'll write up some notes on this later...

Comment: That would be helpful. @Winther

Comment: @Winther When you say take the Fourier transform w.r.t $x$ and $y$, do you mean take the Fourier transform w.r.t $x$ and then take the Fourier transform of this equation w.r.t $y$? Or have I interpreted this wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to take the 2d FT over $x$ *and* $y$ (integration limits are $-\infty\to\infty$ in all integrals below):
$$\hat{g}(k_x,k_y) \equiv \iint g(x',y')e^{-ik_xx'-ik_yy'}\,{\rm d}x'\,{\rm d}y' .$$
and with this convention the inverse transform is given by
$$g(x,y) \equiv \frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\iint \hat{g}(k_x,k_y)e^{ik_xx + ik_yy}\,{\rm d}k_x\,{\rm d}k_y .$$
This transforms your equation $u_{xx} + u_{yy} + k^2u = f(x, y)$ to
$$\hat{u}(k_x,k_y)(-k_x^2-k_y^2+k^2) = \iint f(x',y')e^{-ik_xx' - ik_yy'}\,{\rm d}x'\,{\rm d}y'$$
Now dividing by $(-k_x^2-k_y^2+k^2)$ and taking the inverse transform you end up with the answer in the book (up to a renaming of the integration labels $x'\to \zeta$, $y'\to \eta$ etc.). Just be careful to not reuse an integration label already in use (this is a very common mistake and is why I used $x',y'$ instead of $x,y$ in defining the transform above).

---

When deriving this solution I made the implicit assumption that the FT exists (in the sense of a Riemann integral). When we take $f = 0$ we get $u = 0$ and this is indeed a solution. However this is only one of the solutions (and the same goes with the solution above). For example $u(x,y) = \sin(kx)$ is also a solution. The most general solution is obtained by adding the solution of the homogeneous equation $u_{xx} + u_{yy} + k^2u = 0$. None of the solutions of this equation has a FT (e.g. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(kx)e^{-ik_xx}{\rm d}x$ does not converge) in the traditional sense. The FT can be extended to a larger class of functions which has a FT in what we call a [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Tempered_distributions_and_Fourier_transform) (for which [Dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) is one example) and we could make the derivation above work to produce these solutions, but that is a longer story (what changes is that an equation like $k\hat{u}(k) = \hat{f}$ no longer implies $\hat{u} = \frac{\hat{f}}{k}$ but rather $\hat{u} = \frac{\hat{f}}{k} + C\delta(k)$). Anyway [separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables) is a better way of solving the homogeneous equation if needed.

Comment: Sorry to awaken an old post, but I was wondering why in your first equation the order of integration $dx', \ dy'$ is necessary? Why not simply $dx, \ dy$?

Comment: Yep. I don't quite understand this concept. Why is it needed when taking the inverse? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: @Betty What I said above was just confusing so let's start over: it does not matter what you call the integration label, because all they are is labels telling you to integrate a function of some variable with respect to that variable so for example $\int_0^1 f(x){\rm d}x = \int_0^1 f(y) {\rm d}y = \int_0^1 f(z) {\rm d}z = \ldots$.

Comment: Sometimes it might be convenient to use a different symbol (as we cannot have the same symbol twice if we have more integrals). For example if I write $u(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int \hat{u}(k) e^{-ikx}{\rm d}k$ where $\hat{u}(k) = \int b(x)e^{ikx}{\rm d}x$ then if I want to substitute the last equation into the first I must call the integration variable $x$ something else as $x$ is already used as a variable name in the first equation so I would first write $\hat{u}(k) = \int b(x')e^{ikx'}{\rm d}x'$  and then substitute it in to the equation.

Comment: When dealing with equations with Fourier transforms and inverse this happens very often which is likely why I choose to call it $x'$ instead of $x$. But for what I have written here it doesn't matter. If you like $x$ better use that :)

Comment: This is wonderfully explained. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just one last question :) how do you determine the order of integration when taking the inverse Fourier transform? (also +1)

Comment: @Betty It does not matter here. In this case you wont be able to do the integrals (the answer is given as an integral expression). In general it makes sense to do the easy integrals first like those that will give you a delta function.

Comment: So carrying on from your original, does this mean that the inverse of  $\hat{u}$ is $$u(x,y)=\iint\iint \frac{f(x',y')}{(-k_x^2-k_y^2+k^2)}e^{-i(k_xx'+k_yy')+i(k_xx+k_yy)} dk_x \ dk_y \ dx' \ dy'?$$ (leaving out the constant depending on which definition of the Fourier transform chosen).

Comment: @Betty Yes. And the constant will always be $\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}$. Different definitions of the FT has different constants, but when taking a FT and then and inverse FT the product of these constants will always be the same (to make sure that $\mathbb{F}^{-1}[\mathbb{F}[f]] = f$).

Comment: Awesome! It's also perfectly okay to make the transformations $k_x\rightarrow -\lambda$ and $k_y\rightarrow -\mu$ (I was thinking of using even/odd properties of Fourier transform, but this seems more obvious)?

Comment: Sure, that is just a normal substitution. Just remember that $dk_x = -d\lambda$ and the integration limits $-\infty \to +\infty$ switches to $+\infty \to -\infty$.

Comment: Yep, understood. I just wasn't sure if $\lambda>0$ and $\mu>0$. This isn't so right?

Comment: No it's over all real numbers.